# how to populate a particular property to the formControl with Mat-Option

Tags: angular

```
<mat-select *ngIf="action=='Create';else elseBlock" formControlName="TenantId" required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let type of clientList" [value]="type.tenantId">
       {{type.tenantName}}
     </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```
    this.createPermissionForm.controls.TenantId.valueChanges.subscribe((res: number) => {
console.log(res); 
}
```

instead of logging type.tenantId, it is logging type.tenantName
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add a stacklitz demo? I don't exactly understand what's the problem here, neither your doubts.

Comment: hope that you are trying to do `this.createPermissionForm.controls.TenantId.setValue(someTenantId)`. but there is probably a better way